# How can I fix my queue's "remove" method

Tags: java, queue

My queue uses a stack hence I have two stacks.. `s1` that accepts the add, then all of its items get moved  into `s2` which makes `s2` my queue.

(no use of arrays..)

here is my implementation but when I test it, my remove unit test fails.

```
public class Queue
{
    private Stack s1;
    private Stack s2;

    private int size;


    public Queue()
    {
        //arbitrary sized.
        s1 = new Stack();
        s2 = new Stack();

        size = 0;
    }

    public void insert(Object o)
    {
        //add object into s1.
        s1.push(o);

        size++;
    }

    //delete from queue
       public Object remove()
       {
          int n = 0; ... arbitrary size n. //size not specified
          for(int i = 1; i <= n ; i++)
         {
           //push all elements in s1 into s2 
           s2.insert(s1.pop());
         }                 

          //decrease the size
          size--;

         return s2.pop; 
       }
    public Object peekFront()
    {
        s2.push(s1.pop());


        return s2.peek();
    }


}
```

TEST

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;


public class QueueTest 
{
   protected Queue q;

   public QueueTest()
   {
      q = new Queue();
   }

   atTest
   public void testRemove()
       {
         assertTrue(q.isEmpty()); -- passes

         q.insert(10);
         q.insert(11);
         q.insert(12);
         q.insert(23);

         //remove
         assertEquals(10, q.remove()); --- fails

       }


   public void testPeekFront()
   {
     q.insert(80);
     q.insert(90);
     q.insert(57);

     assertEquals(20,q.peekFront());

   }
}
```

Please can you put me in the right direction on why my `public Object remove` is not functioning correctly...

For example when I try to remove 23? My test passes but when I test for 10 which actually should be, then it fails.

Here is the complete code..... for both the class and the test...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be providing a static value for n. As the value n , will change dynamically, please make sure you are giving n=s1.size() [or any custom function to calculate size]. Please provide the complete code.

Assumed Fixes:
 1. You are popping out all elements from s1 , during remove. Making it(s1) empty stack. So you have to fill it back by popping the values from s2 in the remove function itself. As fabian mentioned in the next answer use a helper method for transfering of elements from 1 stack to another.
2.In remove() method, store s1.pop() to a temp variable and remove all elements in s2. return temp variable. Other wise s2 will keep on growing.
 3. set n = s1.size();
 4. return s1.pop();

Comment: Even if you use this fix, the following sequence of operations would not yield correct results: insert, insert, remove, insert, remove

Comment: @fabian : can you elaborate ? Ex: Insert 1:insert 2. stack [1,2], remove(), stack [2] ,insert 3 stack [2,3]. remove() stack [3]. It seems correct for me.

Comment: @Atinuke: can you check with this fix ?

Comment: `insert(1) insert(2) remove()` This moves all elements from `s1` to `s2` (`s2 = [2]`); `insert(3) remove()` this now moves the rest of the elements from `s1` to `s2` which will be added on top, i.e. `remove` returns `3` instead of `2`.

Comment: Fabian: Oh , yes. In that case he should store s2.pop into a temp variable, then pop out all values in s2[empty s2 completely]. Then return the temp variable.

Comment: can you please explain better @fabian and shijo joseph

Comment: @Atinuke: Can you edit it and provide your complete code .

Comment: my error    === QueueTest.testRemove ===
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<10> but was:<23>
 at QueueTest.testRemove(QueueTest.java:12)

Comment: @fabian I did provide it all

Comment: Is this the code ?

int n = 0; ... arbitrary size n. //size not specified . what is this statement ?

Comment: @Atinuke : Hope it fixed the issue. Please let me know if you have any more doubts.

Comment: @Atinuke: If you find it useful please up vote our answers.

Answer (score 0):

For the method to work you cannot simply hardcode the size. Furthermore you have to move the elements back to the original stack before the next insertion, or the order becomes wrong. I recommend transfering the objects in a helper method to avoid code duplication:

```
private static void transfer(Stack source, Stack target) {
     while (!source.isEmpty()) {
         target.push(source.pop());
     }
}
```

I recommend moving the elements lazily to avoid unnecessary operations for repeated `insert` or repeated `remove` operations:

```
public void insert(Object o) {
    // lazily transfer values back
    transfer(s2, s1);

    //add object into s1.
    s1.push(o);

    size++;
}

//delete from queue
public Object remove() {
    if (s1.isEmpty() && s2.isEmpty()) {
         return null; // alternative: throw exception
    }
    transfer(s1, s2);
    //decrease the size
    size--;
    return s2.pop();
}

public Object peekFront() {
    if (s1.isEmpty() && s2.isEmpty()) {
        return null; // alternative: throw exception
    }

    transfer(s1, s2);

    return s2.peek();
}
```

---

Alternatively you could simply transfer the values back to `s1` in the `remove` method, which would make it a bit simpler to implement additional operations, however it would also make some operation sequences less efficient. (You also still need to fix `peekFront()`):

```
//delete from queue
public Object remove() {
    if (s1.isEmpty() && s2.isEmpty()) {
         return null; // alternative: throw exception
    }
    transfer(s1, s2);

    //decrease the size
    size--;

    Object result = s2.pop();

    transfer(s2, s1);
    return result;
}
```